# Trying export PS script results to email body and send it by email but script Only on my local machine but doesn't work on windows server

Tags: powershell, skype-for-business

I am trying to export script results to an email body and send it. The script works on my local machine but when I use the same script on the
server I receive the email but the body is empty with no results.

I did check the  PowerShell ExecutionPolicy but the same issue. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
$scr = .\Test-CertificateStore.ps1 | Out-String
$FromAddress = "sender"
$ToAddress = "reciver"
$MessageSubject = "Cert test"
$SendingServer = "SMTP"
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $FromAddress, $ToAddress, $MessageSubject,$scr
$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient $SendingServer
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

Comment: The question in your title does not match your description, and neither of those match the code you posted.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: "*the body is empty*", means that `$scr` is probably empty, which means that `\Test-CertificateStore.ps1` doesn't exist or is faulty.

Comment: iRon, thank you for your reply but  I can see the results in PowerShell pane but the email body still empty. so script run successfully and I get the results but only in PowerShell result pane.

Comment: I can see the results below Only in PowerShell pane but nothing in the email body:Check #1 – Misplaced certificates in Trusted Root CA
No misplaced certificate found in Trusted Root CA.

Comment: What happens when you change the content to something else, like:  `$scr = "Test"`?

Comment: Hi iRon, I changed $scr = "Test" as you suggested and I received email with "test" in the body of the email

Comment: Could you post the contents of Test-CertificateStore.ps1? Since setting "Test" works, it definitely a problem with the script.